# I am trying to convert jquery into vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably an easy solution but right now I can't figure out how to make it work

```
$(".a").click(function () {
  if ($("#btnCollapse").css('display')!='none')
    $("#btnCollapse").click();
});
```

Then I tried using vanilla js, I know I am missing something....

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll(".a");   
var button = document.querySelectorAll("#btnCollapse");

function collapseNav() {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function() { 
   button.style.display="none"
  });
  button.click();
}
```

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/   this website is a great tool if you want to 'get rid of' jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a nodelist so you need to loop through its result.

For the `#bntCollapse` use `querySelector`, it returns as single element. For elements with an `id`, and if you need to find many, you can use `getElementById`, which is faster than `querySelector`

To get the style, use `window.getComputedStyle` as it will return a style being set using external CSS as well, which `element.style.display` won't.

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btnCollapse");
    if (window.getComputedStyle(btn,null).getPropertyValue("display") != 'none') {
      btn.click();
    }
  })
}
```

*Note, you can use `foreach` to loop the elements, though based on how, in IE, Edge and Safari it might not work, so test it thoroughly, therefore I used a `for..loop` for maximum browser support.*

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of elements, not a single one, hence you need to loop over it. The button has an `id` so you can select it using `querySelector()` to get a single instance back.

You also have no `collapseNav()` function in the jQuery version so your event handler will be added on load.

Finally the logic is not the same. In the jQuery you only click the button if it's `display` is not `none`. Try this:

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll(".a");   
var button = document.querySelector("#btnCollapse");

anchor.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    if (button.style.display != 'none')
      button.click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [closure-in-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example),

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll(".a");   
var button = document.querySelectorAll("#btnCollapse");
Array.from(anchor).forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(button.style.display!="none"){
            button.click();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct conversion of your "jQuery" code:

```
if (button.style.display != 'none')
    button.click();
```